# PHP round return-value

Tags: php, return-value, rounding

When I run:

```
echo var_dump(round(544/320,3));
```

it prints:

```
float(1.6:)
```

Why does it return a float of 1.6 with a colon at the end? When it clearly should be 1.7.

EDIT: I'm using PHP 5.2.17 on Windows

Comment: http://codepad.org/B2ABnXde (output: `float(1.7)`)

Comment: I'm running this exact same code and I get 1.7.  What is your environment/version?

Comment: What version of PHP (the exact one, from php.ini) it might be that you are using a branch with a bug in it, as we do not experience what you claim to.

Comment: @Tony, I think it's colon not comma.

Answer (score 4):

this is a known bug in PHP where a colon ":" appears in a float value after certain floating point operations such as round() and number_format().

You best bet would be to upgrade to a newer version of PHP.

See this link for more details about the bug.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49764